# User-Defined Types (PL/SQL) in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, oracle11g, oracleforms

I'm using PL/SQL, and I've recently found out that you can do OOP with it. 
The thing is that I've created an Object Type on database level with, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE customer AS OBJECT
(
   customer_id     NUMBER(10)
  ,customer_name   VARCHAR2(30)
  ,customer_last   VARCHAR2(30)

  ,constructor function customer(p_id NUMBER)
      RETURN SELF AS RESULT

  ,member procedure display
)
```

And the type's body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY customer AS

   constructor function customer(p_id NUMBER)
      RETURN SELF AS RESULT
   AS
   BEGIN
      SELECT  client_id,
              client_name,
              client_last
      INTO    self.customer_id,
              self.customer_name,
              self.customer_last
      FROM    clients
      WHERE   client_id = p_id;

      RETURN;
   END;

   member procedure display IS
   BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line('Name: ' || customer_name||' '|| customer_last);
   END;
END;
```

This compiles great and has no problems. 
The thing is when I try to use this new type on Oracle Forms.

I have a very simple form, with just a textbox to put the client_id, and a button to search for the customer (it uses the constructor function from the customer type to create a new instance and return it), and another textbox where it displays the customer name. When pressed it executes a Program Unit that goes like this:

```
 PROCEDURE search_client IS

   client   customer;

 BEGIN

   IF :CLIENT.ID_CLIENT IS NOT NULL THEN 
        client := customer(p_id => :CLIENT.ID_CLIENT);

        :CLIENT.NAME := client.customer_name;
   END IF;      

 END;
```

When I try to compile it, I'm getting this errors:

Error 0 in Line 3, column 11
  Item ignored

and a few more errors like that.

I've read somewhere that client side PLSQL does not support this kind of defined types. Is that true? Or there's any other mistakes that I'm no seen here.

By the way I'm using Oracle Forms 11g, and an Oracle 10g Data base.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right. Forms is only capable of handling the basic types (number, varchar2, etc.)